# Need a PowerShell script to find folders which does not have files modified yesterday

Tags: powershell, compare, backup

Loop through a text file which contains folder Locations

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content "C:\Backup\sample.txt") {
    Get-ChildItem $line | Where {
        $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
    } | select Directoryname, Name, LastWriteTime, @{Name="Size (GB)"; Expression={[Math]::Round($_.Length/1MB, 1)}}
}
```

This way I am only able to get the files that were modified yesterday.

What I want is to list out the folders which does and does not have files modified yesterday.

If a folder contains files that were modified yesterday (modified date as yesterday), then list those File Names, Folder Name and their sizes(GB).

And also `Write-Host` as backup successful.

The same should go with folders which does not contain files with the modified date as yesterday.
`Write-Host` backup not complete.

Comment: just invert the `where` condition: `-lt` or `-le` instead of `-gt`

Comment: Do you consider the backup incomplete if none of the directories has any files modified yesterday, or if at least one of them has no files modified yesterday?

Comment: To match a distinct date when comparing dates you'll have to strip off the time component by appending `.Date`. To check that none of the files is from that date, you could either abort if only one matches or count the matches and only trigger if count is zero. ALSO what should your calculated property return for Length if only folders should be output?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I want the status of each folder to be verified by checking the file modified date. If it has a file modified date as yesterday, that means backup successful. If not, not complete.

Comment: @LotPings Folder names to be mentioned only if Backup is not complete. Output should have 2 headers. In-Complete Backups and Complete backups. Under in-complete backups should only show the folder name. and under complete backup should show file name, directory name, size(GB).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you consider the backup incomplete if at least one folder does not contain a file modified in the past 24 hours.

```
$refdate  = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$complete = $true
$results = foreach ($line in Get-Content "C:\Backup\sample.txt") {
    $result = Get-ChildItem $line |
              Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $refdate } |
              Select-Object Directoryname, Name, LastWriteTime,
                  @{n="Size (GB)";e={[Math]::Round($_.Length/1MB, 1)}}
    if ($result) {
        $result
    } else {
        $complete = $false
    }
}

if ($complete) {
    Write-Host 'Backup complete'
} else {
    Write-Host 'Backup incomplete'
}
```